# How can a background image be automatically added to selected pages in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a long Word document with plain text exported from another software and would like to add a background picture covering the full page on every 7th page (first page with background - 2nd to 6th blank; 7th with background - 8th to 12th blank, etc.)

Since the document is so long, I would like word to do it automatically for me, instead of spending hours just copy, pasting and most probably formatting.

I have seen that there is a way of having header and footer in the pages you want by splitting the document in sections (find [Use a document's section breaks to vary the header or footer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-headers-and-footers-f22334fb-4455-4b18-9354-7c9c70c3b032)), however, the sections would have to be done manually as well.

Is there a way to do this automatically?